# Problem with oddo v11 = ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm new working with oddo v11, and I'm getting the next error when try to running odoo

This the output:

```
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 167764 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando wkhtmltox (0.12.1) sobre (0.12.1) ...
Configurando wkhtmltox (0.12.1) ...
Procesando disparadores para man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
jose@jose-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:/opt/odoo$ sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage
jose@jose-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:/opt/odoo$ sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
jose@jose-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:/opt/odoo$ cd /opt/odoo/odoo
jose@jose-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:/opt/odoo/odoo$ ./odoo-bin
2020-02-15 04:34:46,420 18404 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 11.0
2020-02-15 04:34:46,421 18404 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/jose/.local/share/Odoo/addons/11.0', '/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo/odoo/addons']
2020-02-15 04:34:46,421 18404 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2020-02-15 04:34:46,460 18404 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on jose-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:8069
2020-02-15 04:34:46,621 18404 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

2020-02-15 04:35:33,745 18404 INFO ? odoo.addons.sms.wizard.send_sms: The `phonenumbers` Python module is not available. Phone number validation will be skipped. Try `pip3 install phonenumbers` to install it.
2020-02-15 04:35:34,213 18404 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2020-02-15 04:35:34,218 18404 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2020-02-15 04:35:34,221 18404 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2020 04:35:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2020-02-15 04:35:34,226 18404 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 348, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 166, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 154, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1295, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1458, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1390, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1542, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1509, in db_list
    dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 369, in list_dbs
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 637, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 178, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 520, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 588, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  no existe el rol «jose»
2020-02-15 04:45:23,773 18404 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2020-02-15 04:45:23,775 18404 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2020 04:45:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2020-02-15 04:45:23,785 18404 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 348, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 166, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 154, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1295, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1458, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1390, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1542, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1509, in db_list
    dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 369, in list_dbs
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 637, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 178, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 520, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 588, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  no existe el rol «jose»
```

And if someone could you help me with this problem I'd thank you a lot. I've configured Oddo with these commands.

https://github.com/mtsoftware2016/odoo11/blob/master/commands.txt#L32

Thx for reading.

Comment: Thank you for your question, it helped me to better troubleshoot and resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`no existe el rol «jose»`

This error means you are trying to connect with Postgresql Database with `db_user` `jose` which doesn't exists.

Create DB user for Odoo and provide `db_user` and `db_password` accordingly in the Odoo config file by :

> sudo su postgres
>
> createuser -s odoo
>
> createuser -s your_user_name
>
> exit

and try to connect again by change directory to `cd /odoo/odoo-server` 
then type and run `./odoo-bin`

Comment: Thank you.  Although your answer didn't directly answer my needs, it assisted in how to better troubleshoot the issue.